# Why is my code executing although it should pause?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, asynchronous

I have an API which is limited regarding how many requests per minute (50/minute) I can send to any endpoint provided by that API.

In the following code-section, I filter the objects `orders` with an URL as property, every object with an URL that provides data should be stored in `successfullResponses` in my `app.component.ts`.

```
Promise.all(
orders.map(order => this.api.getURL(order.resource_url).catch(() => null))
).then(responses => {
  const successfulResponses = responses.filter(response => response != null)
  for(let data of successfulResponses) {
       // some other requests should be sent with data here
  }
});
```

There are more than 50 `orders` to check, but I just can check maximum 50 `orders` at once, so I try to handle it in my service. I set the first date when the first request is sent. After that I compare the dates of the new request with the first one. If the difference is over 60, I set the current date to the new one and set `maxReq` again to 50. If it is under 60, I check if there are requests left, if yes I send the request and if not I just wait one minute :

```
sleep(ms){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async getURL(){
      if(!this.date){
        let date = new Date();
        this.date = date;
      }
      if((new Date().getSeconds() - this.date.getSeconds() > 60 )){
        this.maxReq = 50;
        this.date = new Date();
        return this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions).toPromise();
      } else {
        if(this.maxReq > 0){
          this.maxReq -= 1;
          return this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions).toPromise();
        } else{
          console.log("wait");
         await this.sleep(60*1000);
         this.maxReq = 50;
         this.date = new Date();
         return this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions).toPromise();
        }
      }
  }
```

However the code in `app.component.ts`is not waiting for the function `getURL()` and executes further code with requests which leads to the problem that I send ´too many requests too quickly´.
What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while trying to use promises with multiple async functions. It's an easy thing to forget, but in order to make them all wait, you have to use `await` on the root line that calls the function in question.

I'm not entirely certain, but my presumption is that your `await this.sleep(60*1000);` line is indeed waiting for a timeout to occur, but whilst it is doing this, the code that called `getURL()` is executing the rest of its lines, because it did not have an `await` (or equivalent, like `.then`) before `getURL()`.

The way I discovered this in my case was by using a good debugging tool (I used Chrome DevTools's own debugging features). I advise you do the same, adding breakpoints everywhere, and see where your code is going with each line.

Here is a short, rough example to show what I mean:

```js
// This code increments a number from 1 to 2 to 3 and returns it each time after a delay of 1 second.

async function loop() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        console.log('Input start');
        /* The following waits for result of aSync before continuing.
           Without 'await', it would execute the last line
           of this function whilst aSync's own 'await'
           waited for its result.
           --- This is where I think your code goes wrong. --- */
        await aSync(i);
        console.log('Input end');
    }
}

async function aSync(num) {
    console.log('Return start');
    /* The following waits for the 1-second delay before continuing.
       Without 'await', it would return a pending promise immediately
       each time. */
    let result = await new Promise(
        // I'm not using arrow functions to show what it's doing more clearly.
        function(rs, rj) {
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    /* For those who didn't know, the following passes the number
                       into the 'resolved' ('rs') parameter of the promise's executor
                       function. Without doing this, the promise would never be fulfilled. */
                    rs(num);
                }, 1000
            )
        }
    );
    console.log(result);
    console.log('Return end');
    
}

loop();
```